# Logon Fail Integration Services 2012

Tags: sql-server, authentication, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2012-datatools

I have a SSIS Project deployed in SQL Server. The connection manager in the project are linked to a server name that is not the one where the SSIS project is deployed. After i execute the master package in sql server errors pop ups in the report screen: Login Failed for NT Authority\Anonymous Logon.

Is this a double hop attempt?

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the permission form your deployment server to the server in your connection manager.

Comment: But is it possible to do what I'm trying to do? After a time doing research of the error I though this was double hop since I have my sis project deployed in one server and I'm trying to access another server through the connection manager using windows authentication in them. Thank you for responding to my questions.

Comment: About the permission the client gave me full access. The error being shown is login failed NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON

Comment: Let see if I get this correctly, the server where the connection manager are pointing must allow the other server to access data. The problem is not that me as user is given full access is that the server where the project is deployed doesn't have the right to access the data the packages are looking. Is this the approach you are recommending?